# How fix broken css in component

Tags: html, css

I took the component, however, for some reason the styles are not the same as in the example on the official website.
I don't understand why the cards stretched across my entire table, as well as the search bar and the display of elements moved to the left.

How to fix it?

It is necessary that the cards when choosing to display in blocks are displayed as in the picture, but for some reason they are in a row.

[image]

```css
:host ::ng-deep .p-dropdown {
    width: 14rem;
    font-weight: normal;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-name {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 700;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-description {
    margin: 0 0 1rem 0;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-category-icon {
    vertical-align: middle;
    margin-right: 0.5rem;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-category {
    font-weight: 600;
    vertical-align: middle;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    padding: 1rem;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item img {
    width: 150px;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    margin-right: 2rem;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-list-detail {
    flex: 1 1 0;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .p-rating {
    margin: 0 0 0.5rem 0;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-price {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
    align-self: flex-end;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-list-action {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .p-button {
    margin-bottom: 0.5rem;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item {
    margin: 0.5em;
    border: 1px solid #dee2e6;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item .product-grid-item-top, :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item .product-grid-item-bottom {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    justify-content: space-between;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item img {
    width: 75%;
    box-shadow: 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.16), 0 3px 6px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23);
    margin: 2rem 0;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item .product-grid-item-content {
    text-align: center;
  }
  :host ::ng-deep .product-grid-item .product-price {
    font-size: 1.5rem;
    font-weight: 600;
  }
  .card {
    padding: 2rem;
    box-shadow: 0 2px 1px -1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 1px 1px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.14), 0 1px 3px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.12);
    border-radius: 4px;
    margin-bottom: 2rem;
  }
  @media screen and (max-width: 576px) {
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item {
      flex-direction: column;
      align-items: center;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item img {
      width: 75%;
      margin: 2rem 0;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-list-detail {
      text-align: center;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-price {
      align-self: center;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-list-action {
      display: flex;
      flex-direction: column;
    }
    :host ::ng-deep .product-list-item .product-list-action {
      margin-top: 2rem;
      flex-direction: row;
      justify-content: space-between;
      align-items: center;
      width: 100%;
    }
  }
```

```html
<div class="card">
    <p-dataView #dv [value]="products" [paginator]="true" [rows]="9" filterBy="name"
        [sortField]="sortField" [sortOrder]="sortOrder" layout="grid">
        <ng-template pTemplate="header">
            <div class="flex flex-column md:flex-row md:justify-content-between">
                <p-dropdown [options]="sortOptions" [(ngModel)]="sortKey" placeholder="Sort By Price" (onChange)="onSortChange($event)" styleClass="mb-2 md:mb-0"></p-dropdown>
                <span class="p-input-icon-left mb-2 md:mb-0">
                    <i class="pi pi-search"></i>
                    <input type="search" pInputText placeholder="Search by Name" (input)="dv.filter($event.target.value)">
                </span>
                <p-dataViewLayoutOptions></p-dataViewLayoutOptions>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-product pTemplate="listItem">
            <div class="p-col-12">
                <div class="product-list-item">
                    <div class="product-list-detail">
                        <div class="product-name">{{product.name}}</div>
                        <div class="product-description">{{product.description}}</div>
                        <p-rating [ngModel]="product.rating" [readonly]="true" [cancel]="false"></p-rating>
                        <i class="pi pi-tag product-category-icon"></i><span class="product-category">{{product.category}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-list-action">
                        <span class="product-price">${{product.price}}</span>
                        <p-button icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" label="Add to Cart" [disabled]="product.inventoryStatus === 'OUTOFSTOCK'"></p-button>
                        <span [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
        <ng-template let-product pTemplate="gridItem">
            <div class="col-12 md:col-4">
                <div class="product-grid-item card">
                    <div class="product-grid-item-top">
                        <div>
                            <i class="pi pi-tag product-category-icon"></i>
                            <span class="product-category">{{product.category}}</span>
                        </div>
                        <span [class]="'product-badge status-' + product.inventoryStatus.toLowerCase()">{{product.inventoryStatus}}</span>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-grid-item-content">
                        <div class="product-name">{{product.name}}</div>
                        <div class="product-description">{{product.description}}</div>
                        <p-rating [ngModel]="product.rating" [readonly]="true" [cancel]="false"></p-rating>
                    </div>
                    <div class="product-grid-item-bottom">
                        <span class="product-price">${{product.price}}</span>
                        <p-button icon="pi pi-shopping-cart" [disabled]="product.inventoryStatus === 'OUTOFSTOCK'"></p-button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </ng-template>
    </p-dataView>
</div>
```

Comment: The "HTML" shown is more Angular than HTML.  If the problem really is with just styling elements then you'll likely want to isolate the actual HTML structure you're trying to produce and style that structure.  *Then* apply that structure to your Angular application.  Currently the executed result looks *absolutely nothing* like the picture.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I can see that the code is taken from PrimeNG, the set of Angular UI components. For these components to perform like in demo, it will require some preparation and the following tools to be installed locally:

1. Node.js
2. Angular CLI
3. PrimeNG set
4. Bootstrap

To save you some time, you can familiarize yourself with the following code, scan carefully through its structure in this StackBlitz sandbox: https://stackblitz.com/edit/primeng-dataview-demo

I also highly suggest that you read through the Angular documentation:
https://angular.io/docs.

They also have a highly entertaining introduction to their framework through the development of a small application: https://angular.io/tutorial/tour-of-heroes